# Как исправить ошибку Undefined offset при использовании explode()?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Как убрать лишние ключи в массиве, если в них из базы прилетает NULL?

```
$app_part = Иванова Иван Иванович

$app_part_exp = explode (' ',$app_part);

$app_part_exp_f = $app_part_exp[0];

$app_part_exp_i = $app_part_exp[1];

$app_part_exp_o = $app_part_exp[2];

$fio_part = "%$app_part_exp_f%$app_part_exp_i%$app_part_exp_o%";
```

т.е. чтобы если я введу только Иванов Иван, 2 ключ он не присоединял в переменную  `$fio_part`.

Сейчас IIS пишет в логе такое:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\fio.php on line 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всякий раз, когда у тебя переменные с именами по порядку, ты что-то делаешь не так.

В данном случае можно обойтись совсем без массива:

```
$app_part = "Иванова Иван Иванович";
$fio_part = "%".str_replace(" ", "%", $app_part)."%";
```

А в общем случае, чтобы соединить элементы массива через определённую строку, надо не разбивать массив на переменные, а использовать implode()

```
$app_part = "Иванова Иван Иванович";
$parts    = preg_split('/\W+/', $app_part, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$fio_part = "%".implode("%", $parts)."%";
```

Comment: В базе для фамилии имени отчества отдельные поля.
При выборке я их в запросе группирую и подставляю в where условие $fio_part .

Comment: Всё это выглядит как "надевать штаны через голову". Зачем нужно из массива раскидывать данные по отдельным переменным - совершенно непонятно.

Comment: В поле поиска откуда прилетает в $app_part, могут ввести отдельно фамилию или имя и отчество или только имя и т.д.

Shorty, сначала ругался на iconv, добавил. Теперь результат 0 и ошибок нету.

Comment: На вопрос "Зачем нужно из массива раскидывать данные по отдельным переменным" ваш комментарий никак не отвечает. От слова "совсем".

Comment: $app_part = "Иванова Иван Иванович";
$fio_part = "%".str_replace(" ", "%", $app_part)."%";
Это помогло. Спасибо.

Comment: @Shorty, `/\s+/`?

Comment: @ArtemRemizov, а что будете делать, если пробелов больше одного? MySQL, конечно, слопает конструкцию вида `"%Иванов%%%Иван%"`, но легче ему от этого не будет :-)